# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, mysql, typeerror

I am trying to take the excel data which is the var 'y' which is numerical data and put it into my SQL column 'Close'.

```
import xlrd
import MySQLdb

#get excel data
file_location = "C:/Users/.../.../...xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1.1")
y = sheet.col_values(3, start_rowx=2, end_rowx=31)

#open connection SQL
db=MySQLdb.connect(host = "host",
                    user = "user",
                    passwd = "passwd",
                    db = "test")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""UPDATE uk SET Close.....""")

db.commit()
```

However i am not sure what to write to insert it.

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE uk SET Close = %s""", (y,))
```

Gives the error that:

```
OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

Thank you for any help or direction you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting 2 commas:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE uk SET Close = %s""", (y,))
```

Without those, you are executing:

```
"""..."""(y)
```

e.g. trying to call the string object as if it was a function.